# how do i get the number of clients from an Ap cisco and save it in a variable?

Tags: python, linux, snmp, pysnmp, pyasn1

I hope you can help me,
The goal is to get the number of clients that have conected to the ap using pysnmp, I think I'm close, I know I have to use probably pyasn1, but I get to a part that gives me the following error:

**('---------->', DisplayString('', subtypeSpec=ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(),ValueSizeConstraint(0, 255)),ValueSizeConstraint(0, 255))))**

My code is this:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
from pysnmp.proto import rfc1905

setcommunity = "public"
host = "192.168.1.51"
oid = '1.3.6.1.4.1.1.4.1.14179.2.1.1.1.38'
ssid = "Cisco1852i"
snmp_engine = SnmpEngine()

#this function gets the interface status of the cisco Switch

def show_apClients():
       clients = nextCmd (snmp_engine,
               CommunityData(setcommunity),
               UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),
               ContextData(),

       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-SMI', 'mib-2', '1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.1.1.1.38')))
       errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(clients) 
       numberClients = varBinds[0][1]
       print("----------->", numberClients)
       return numberClients

nClients = show_apClients()

print(".....------->", nClients)
```

I think the OID, the MIB and the rest are all right, because I through the command:

"*sudo snmpwalk.py -v 2c -c public 192.168.1.51 1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.1.4.1.7 | wc -l*"

or

"*sudo snmpwalk.py -v 2c -c public 192.168.1.51 1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.1.1.18*"
I can get the command line the number of clients

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate this Net-SNMP command with pysnmp:

```
snmpwalk.py -v 2c -c public 192.168.1.51 1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.1.4.1.7 | wc -l
```

then I guess you should do something like this:

```
def show_apClients():
    clients = nextCmd(
        snmp_engine,
        CommunityData(setcommunity),
        UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),
        ContextData(),
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.1.4.1.7')),
        lexicographicMode=True
    )

    # this iterates over generator
    numberClients = len(tuple(clients))
    print("----------->", numberClients)
    return numberClients
```

The idea is that you let pysnmp walk the `1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.1.4.1.7` branch and return the number of nodes (rows) under that OID prefix. I assume that that reflects the number of users being associated with the AP.

Comment: Thank you for the reply llya, but it didn't work, the result should be 3 and it is giving me 1769.

Comment: @RicardoAlves Pardon me, `lexicographicMode=True` was missing so your got all the OIDs past `1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.1.4.1.7`.

Comment: Thank you again for the reply, but the result is still the same :)

Comment: @RicardoAlves I'd suggest to print out `tuple(clients)` and see which OIDs are reported and whether they correspond to the number of associated APs.

Comment: @RicardoAlves I'd advise you to print out the `tuple(clients)` contents to see which OIDs get there. If your use of SNMP data is correct, the number of OID-value parts there should reflect the number of associated clients. If you are getting wrong count, perhaps some extra OID-value pairs get in there somehow.